# Rails 4 - how to use a helper method in the parent view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, helper

I'm trying to figure out how to use helpers files.

I have models for Project and Potential Use. The associations are:

Project

```
has_many :potential_uses
accepts_nested_attributes_for :potential_uses, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
```

Potential Use

```
belongs_to :project
belongs_to :user
```

In my projects show page, I have a reference to a helper method defined in my projects helper folder:

```
<%= potential_uses_for_viewer(@project) %>
```

The helper method (in projects_helper.rb) has:

```
def potential_uses_for_viewer(project)
  if @current_user.id == @project.profile.user_id 
    render 'potential_uses/private_comments'
  else 
    render 'potential_uses/open_comments'
  end
end
```

I have two view partials in my potential uses view folder. I want to render one of those partials if the current user is the project creator, and another if the current user is not the project creator.

Presently, there are no errors that are rendered, but the helper in the projects folder does not work. Regardless of whether I am logged in as the user that made the project or not, I get the `potential_uses/open_comments` view.

Can anyone see where I've gone wrong?

Comment: what is `@current_user` inside the helper? Did you try to print it to the console?

Comment: @ArunKumar - it's a devise method to see who the logged in user is.

Comment: I guess the method provided by devise is `current_user`. Does my answer resolve your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're receiving an argument `project` in the helper but inside the helper method, you're trying to access `@project.profile.user_id`. `@project` is nil inside the helper. You should use

```
if @current_user.id == project.profile.user_id 
  render 'potential_uses/private_comments'
```

Comment: Thanks Arun  - that makes sense

Comment: Great! Updated my answer.